# Big Query: how to use Variable and loops with column names

Tags: google-bigquery, dml

I am trying to use a loop to update a table in Bigquery. My table structure is as following (with 100 columns and thousands of rows):

| DATE | PERIOD1 | PERIOD2 | PERIOD3 | PERIOD4 | PERIOD5 | PERIOD6 | PERIOD... | PERIOD100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | row |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-02-01 | row |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

For each date, I would need to use a loop to populate the values with something like

```
---
DECLARE VAR_PERIOD INT64 DEFAULT 1
LOOP
IF PERIOD > 100 THEN LEAVE;
END IF;
---
update `mydataset.mytable` set CONCAT('PERIOD',VAR_PERIOD) = (select{+my query})
```

which obviously cannot work, so I'm wondering what alternative method can be used to easily update my table columns ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can try using BigQuery API client libraries [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).
There are more languages available but I am using python here.
You can directly start in cloud shell. There you can write a Python program to
do your job.

There is some assumption I am taking regarding your requirements :
You want to use SELECT clause to get some value and using which you want to
update values of Period columns.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

''' Construct a BigQuery client object. '''
client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    select col_name from `projectID.dataset.table`
    where condition
"""

''' Make an API request. '''
query_job = client.query(query) 

''' Store the value of query result in some variable (value). '''
for row in query_job:
    value = row[0]


'''  
Creating the query to update the columns using the value.
 
UPADTE `projectID.dataset.table`
SET Period1 = Period1 + value, Period2 = Period2 + value ...
where condition
'''

query = "UPDATE `projectID.dataset.table`  SET "

for i in range(1,101):
    query += 'period'+str(i)+' = ' + 'period'+ str(i) + ' + ' +str(value) +','

query = query[0:-1]
query += ' WHERE condition'

''' Make an API request. '''
query_job = client.query(query)
```

All BigQuery Update statement must have a WHERE Clause. If you
want to update all the rows than in WHERE condition mention TRUE [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#where_keyword_2).

Comment: Thank you Chandra for your response. Unfortunately this becomes too complex for my use case, I need to limit the option to BigQuery UI / Console